# viewDidLoad calling before init?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I face a strange situation. In my controller, `viewDidLoad` is calling before `init`. Is there any technical reason behind that?

Answer (score 55):

The `viewDidLoad` method is being called when accessing `self.view` inside the `init` method (since `self.view` should not yet be loaded from the nib the process seems to be fasten so it doesn't return nil).

Comment: So Thank you. self.view in init was my huge problem.

Comment: Thanks, moved any self.view activities to viewDidLoad, and changed all properties that I needed in my designated initialiser from self.property to _property. Solved everything.

Comment: Late comment, I ran into this same problem, but I'm confused how? It just bypasses the constructor?

Comment: @DavidPullar It doesn't bypass it, it just loads the `view` (calling `viewDidLoad`) as soon as it's first used. It's like manually calling `viewDidLoad` from inside `init`.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is a bit old post, but I'll post my point of view anywhere because I think it could help somebody.

Well, I've been in this same situation. I thought that viewDidLoad was being called before init method in my view controller class. But what was really happening was not that: the flow starts on init method, but jumps to viewDidLoad when calling [super init*], so my log messages in viewDidLoad method were being displayed first that those in my custom initialization.

I think that's it. I hope this to save some time to someone.

[Sorry for my English]

Comment: Great observation!

Comment: This helped me. Thanks, Ricard! My app was calling my custom initializer (which called super.init) which caused it to call viewDidLoad before leaving that custom initializer. I ended up calling super.init at the end of my custom initializer so that everything I wanted to set up before viewDidLoad got called was already set up.

Answer (score 12):

### NOTE for `UITabBarController`:

I don't know what kind of UIViewController caused this for you but I faced a similar case with **UITabBarController**.
I thought it might help another one facing it with `UITabBarController`.
As far as I know all viewControllers call init before viewDidLoad, except for the `UITabBarController` and its subclasses.
As Andrew claims [here](http://www.andrewmonshizadeh.com/2015/02/23/uitabbarcontroller-is-different/), `UITabBarController`s call loadView inside `[super init]` method, which causes the call to `viewDidLoad`. So the `viewDidLoad` method will be called before init has finished its job.
If you have some thing to setup in `viewDidLoad` you should perhaps do it inside init method after the call to `[super init]`.

Comment: Have been fighting with my UITabBarController sublcass for an entire day not understaning why some of my variables were nil even though I was setting them before viewDidLoad pas supposed to be called and changing UITabBarController by UIViewController was fixing everything ... As usual apple doesn't tell about any side effects or special cases in their more than lacking docs .....

Answer (score 3):

When you initialise a `UIViewController` from code, you use `-initWithNibName:bundle:`, whereas when it is initialised from a XIB, the XIB loading code will call `-initWithCoder:`. One, and only one of these two methods will be called, and they will definitely be called before `-viewDidLoad`.

There's no conceivable way that `-viewDidLoad` could be called first, unless you are calling it yourself (which you should never really do).

Answer (score 0):

No, the viewDidLoad message is always called *after* init.

Are you sure init is called at all? There are several init methods especially for UIViewController, maybe another one is called instead making you think differently.

If you need more information, please paste the code of viewDidLoad and all of your init methods, and tell us how it is loaded (i.e. with code) or from a nib.

Comment: Yes , init is calling but after viewDidLoad. For that particular UIViewController just alloc and init. and setting that controller to a UITabBarController as a view controller and presenting the tabbarController ? Is any thing wrong here ?

Comment: Init runs before viewDidLoad, unless you messed up really really bad which is very unlikely. You are missing another init or draw wrong conclusions. What makes you think that init is called after viewDidLoad? And have you checked this is the same object? Again, no code - no way to check.

Answer (score -1):

If your ViewController is being loaded from your main nib file, then most likely it is initWithCoder that is being called to initialize the controller.